# How to add CSS3 Animation Effects to Simple jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, css, animation, tabs, effects

I create a jQuery Tabs and is working fine, but I want to add some CSS3 effects like scale, Translate, Transitions..
Now my tab is with only with jQuery effects like fadeIn/slideToggle, but I need to create my custom effects by using CSS3, so how I can add CSS3 animations feature to my Tabs code.

See my code here : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/od798zwq/)

Some CSS3 Code needed for animation Effects :

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
opacity: 1;
```

The Animation I want is when some one click on tab must show tab content from `transform: scale(0.8); to transform: scale(1);`
and `opacity: 0; to opacity: 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the tab title, set a class on the matching `tab-content`, start a timer for just longer than the animation, then remove the class.

```
$(".tabs li").click(function(){
    var  cur =$(".tabs li").index(this);
    var elm = $('.tabcontent:eq('+cur+')');
    elm.addClass("pulse");
    setTimeout(function() {
          elm.removeClass("pulse");
    }, 220);
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/od798zwq/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I want to animate tabcontent not tab title?

Comment: Thank you so much is working now : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/od798zwq/3/)  but sometimes when I click is doesn't work where is the problem?

Comment: @Uikithemes Yeah, actual `toggle()` was a bad fit with the tabs, updated to use `addClass()` and with a timer to call  `removeClass()` instead, much cleaner now.

Comment: awesome is working now like i want thank you so so much for your help :)

Comment: @Uikithemes Glad it helpped!

Answer (score -1):

Set your CSS to a class and then use `.toggleClass()` to apply that to the given element.

So,

```
$("tab").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("myClass");
});
```

And your css would be:

```
.myClass{
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: What is `$("tab").click` binding to?

Comment: @DelightedD0D that's just an example for illustrative purposes, you can change the selector to bind to whatever you want.